# Errors Compiling OpenCV on Debian

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans, compilation, debian

I installed OpenCV from the repos on my Debian Wheezy (64bits). I was able to compile the source file of an example but when it goes to the `build` step this happens:

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/opencvtestapp build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o 

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
/home/ ... /main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::get(int)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:17: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::get(int)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:26: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat&)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:35: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:40: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/home/ ... /main.cpp:40: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:297: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:382: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/opencvtestapp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/work/OpenCVTestApp'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/work/OpenCVTestApp'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I am using NetBeans 8.0 and OpenCV2.3 (from the repo).

**Any suggestions on what I could be missing?**

Thanks!

Comment: ouch. opencv2.3. in 2014 ? but the real problem is, that you don't link *any* opencv libs (opencv_core, opencv_highgui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@berak is totally right on his comment, for that was the problem.

I forgot to add the libraries to the linker configuration. :P

As for 2.3 in 2014: I agree. I am planning to use 3.o alpha but this is what the repo had and I didn't want to compile the whole thing just to run some samples.

Thank you @berac! I hope the question is still useful for someone out there.